# Android Studio : emulator is already running

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to run emulator on my android studio 8.14. When I click run it says it is already running. Any help would be appreciated.

> AVD api21 is already running.
>
> If that is not the case, delete the files at /home/sayem/.android/avd/api21.avd/*.lock and try again

[image: image containing the error written out above]

Comment: Try running `adb stop-server`and then `adb start-server`

Comment: have you try remove lock file at given location and try again.

Comment: thanks.. i removed file at given location but it removes my existing emulator.

Comment: @BlazeTama - t's "kill-server", not "stop-server"

Comment: Please see this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763470/android-studio-cannot-find-the-visual-studio-emulator

Comment: Now, we can use Windows PowerToys's File Locksmith to view which application locks the file in question so that we can terminate the app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/file-locksmith

Answer (score 221, accepted):

You don't have to completely delete the emulator when this happens. The files to delete should have a ".lock" extension:

[image: Screenshot of files for an AVD. The first three files appear as file folders in Windows 7 and have '.lock' at the end of their file names.]

You don't need to touch the configuration files.

You can easily find the files location by clicking on the arrow under the Actions tab (in the ADB manager), and selecting "Show on Disk".

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried doing this, but it won't let me because it says that the files are currently in use. What should I do?

Comment: I thought i just need to delete *.lock file, but it also required to delete *.lock folder.

Comment: @ap Was Android Studio still running? You might try quitting the application first.

Comment: Deleting all the .lock files and restarting the Emulator is what worked form me

Comment: On Windows, this is the only sureshot method (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62676806/2632842) and does not require clearing cache, restarting Studio, rebooting Windows and other such things.

Comment: Nice, had deleted the files but didnt notice the folder also was *.lock lol

Comment: Just remove all *.lock files under the emulator folder.

Answer (score 64):

This worked for me:

Go to AVD Manager and click on the down-arrow on the right and click Stop. This stops the emulator and you can re-run it.

Comment: Most precise answer here because, if we try to delete the *.lock folder, it may simply be denied while this work at first attmpt.

Comment: This worked for me. I was unable to delete the *.lock files it was telling me to delete since "they were in use". So clicking Stop allowed me to delete the AVD.

Comment: "Most precise answer here because" probably for you. That did nothing in my case

Comment: Thanks, It worked. No need to delete files. @Farid In case the delete button was disabled, I changed the Graphics to "automatic" and "stop" button enabled.

Comment: I have to "Stop" action there.

Answer (score 53):

Go to the down arrow and click on the "Show on Disk" link like attached image. You will get the list of all files, remove the file "hardware-qemu.ini.lock" and start again.

It works for me hope it will work for you too.

[image]

Comment: may also need to be deleted in "multiinstance.lock"

Comment: although it allows startup, before the device opens I get "...was terminated", even if I delete `multiinstance.lock` too I had to also delte `snapshot.lock.lock` then device started, but please note this **does not** kill the hanging process of the original device. That can be done with `adb kill-server` - I suggest running that first

Comment: If .lock files are in use, end the **qemu-system-i386.exe** process first, then delete the .lock files.

Answer (score 19):

There are so many answer but i just extending to give answer of this question. What happen is when i follow Android Studio instruction and try to delete that folder Or file but i am not able to delete it, So what am i do is that i open the AVD Manager and click on down arrow which is on right side as you can see in below screenshot and click on **stop** after click on start and its working fine. **There is no need to restart or recreate the AVD.**

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, but when I click "stop", nothing happens.

Comment: I do not have the "stop" there at all.

Answer (score 18):

Follow the instructions on the error and go to your
   `C:\Users\directory\.android\avd/Nexus_5_API_24.avd/*.lock`
 and delete all files with the .lock extension and it should work.

Comment: This is better then other answers (y)

Comment: in my case, this didn't work because my AVD was restarting automatically. So I deleted all files from %temp% and restarted pc and its working fine.

Answer (score 14):

When I was trying to delete **multiinstance.lock** it says

[image]

So, I opened Window's task manager and selected **qemu-system-x86_64.exe** and press **End task**

[image]

Comment: This is what i had to do.

Answer (score 11):

I restarted the computer and it worked for me!

Comment: Nothing else worked for me. Restart is always a good idea!

Answer (score 10):

This working for me :

**Invalidate chaches/ restart**

Go to

1 - File

2 - Select Invalidate Cahes / Restart

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This works for me in 2023 - Window 11.

Answer (score 7):

Use this for killing all emulator processes.

```
adb emu kill
```

Comment: Best answer here, worked like charm

Answer (score 5):

**C:\Users\admin.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_26.avd** follow path and delete  **hardware-qemu.ini.lock** this folder.
make sure your problem can be  solve  :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the already accepted answer. It also assumes the specific emulator being used

Comment: this worked. This should be the accepted answer as of Android Studio 3.+

Answer (score 4):

Find and open the **pid** folder within your *.lock folder. Inside should be a number.

Kill pid:

Windows

```
taskkill /F /PID pid_number
```

Comment: On Windows, this is the most elegant, sureshot method and does not require clearing cache, restarting Studio, rebooting Windows and other such things as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Go to (Windows)

> C:\Users\directory.android\avd/Nexus_5X_API_26.avd

Or (Ubuntu)

> ~/.android/avd/name.avd/Nexus_5X_API_26.avd

and delete all files of with .lock extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks everyone.

I removed files of given location. but when I refresh the AVD manager, Existing emulator are all gone.

I recreated new emulator. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

When you go to the specified location and try to delete those files sometimes you might get an error stating that the file or folder is already open or is used by another application

So the simple Solution is just to go to

```
Tools > Android > AVD Manager and Stop the AVD that you are trying to run
```

Then When you try to run the AVD again you might have the problem resolved

Comment: I have the same issue, but when I click "stop", nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

For me, "delete .lock file" & "stop emulator then start" & "delete emulator then recreate" does't work.

but,delete "**C/User/yourName/.android**" folder can fix this problem

Comment: but this will delete the  emulator also?

Answer (score 3):

> **For MAC Users**

Open Terminal, cd to the given path. List all the files using the command ls. You will see two files with .lock extensions or maybe more. Just delete those files.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

For Windows: Step By Step Instructions below:

1. Locate the avd folder: **C:\Users\username\.android\avd**
2. Try delete *lock and figure out the process holding the lock
3. **Ctrl+Shift+Esc** to get to TaskManager
4. Select Pid and Process name by right clicking on the header
5. Get the PID number of the offending application
6. on cmd type: **taskkill /F /PID /PIDnumber**
7. Now go back to the avd folder & delete the *lock files. It will work.
8. Restart Emulator

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the tips from Android Studio ... Delete the file corresponding to your avd and recreate it.

This happens when the virtual device is shut down in an unexpected state.

Comment: i cant delet it.bacause it runs another program

Answer (score 2):

I Also have the same problem but in ubuntu 20.04 and I had to navigate to `/home/your_username/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_28.avd/*.lock`   and then delete all file with .lock

**Note**: you first need to enable show hidden files and I may have used different device (Pixel_2_API_28) from yours but it is applied to any device

Answer (score 2):

For Linux this should clear them for all devices in one go if your issue is just .lock files

```bash
find $HOME/.android -type f -name '*.lock' -exec rm {} \;
```

Example with it just echoing out.

```
❯ find $HOME/.android -type f -name '*.lock' -exec echo rm {} \;
rm /home/mike/.android/build-cache.lock
rm /home/mike/.android/debug.keystore.lock
rm /home/mike/.android/avd/Pixel_6_Pro_API_33.avd/multiinstance.lock
rm /home/mike/.android/avd/Pixel_6_Pro_API_33.avd/hardware-qemu.ini.lock
rm /home/mike/.android/avd/Pixel_6_Pro_API_30.avd/multiinstance.lock
rm /home/mike/.android/avd/Pixel_6_Pro_API_30.avd/hardware-qemu.ini.lock
rm /home/mike/.android/build-cache/3.5.2.lock
~ at 10:16:27 
❯
```

If you did not stop them all first can run this first beforehand.

```
adb devices | grep emulator | cut -f1 | while read line; do adb -s $line emu kill; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this command and try again:

```
adb kill-server
```

Answer (score 1):

If **"adb kill-server"** dont work try killing the adb from System monitor app of ubuntu:

```
System monitor->processes
```

All processes will be listed here end adb from here, must be in the top of the list.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Settings
2. Goto developer options
3. Click revoke USB debugging authorizations

Answer (score 1):

In your Android Studio go to Tools->Android->AVD Manager. It will list your virtual devices. Click the Action column corresponding to your virtual device. It will list many actions. Click on Stop. This will shutdown your android studio. Now start android studio. Your virtual device should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can type a command in terminal as

1.`killall Finder` and then type,

2.`defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles true` it shows hidden **.android folder**

Open .android folder and delete `.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_26.avd/*.lock file` 
and now you run emulator it works fine.

Comment: Shift+CMD+. = show hidden files in finder

Answer (score 1):

I closed the emulator, clicked the AVD Manager Icon on the menubar then under the emulators actions tab downward arrow I selected "Cold Boot Now" then ran the program normally by pressing SHIFT + F10[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this problem by doing "Invalidate chaches/ restart".

Answer (score 1):

EASIEST SOLUTION:

1. Go to AVD Manager
2. Click on down arrow in the Actions column on the right
3. Click on Wipe data

You're done :)

Comment: Why would you do this when there is a simple solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62676806/2632842

Answer (score 1):

for Linux , create an executable script that contains this (depends on package psmisc ,Artix Linux):

```
#!/bin/bash

#kill x86 + x86_64 emulator instances
killall qemu-system-x86_64 -9
killall qemu-system-i386 -9

# delete all lock-files
for n in `find ~/.android/avd/ -name "*.lock"`; do rm -v $n;done
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the emulator *looked* fine but it was hung.

Just killing the emulator and trying again did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

> `C:\Users\.android\avd`
>   follow the path and open Emulator directory and delete all `.lock` extension folders.

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed all answers, and no success yet. And not able to find that specific lock.

Search all .lock extension files in /avd dir, and remove them. After then start again emultaor. It works for me without restart system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm don't know if some one is still having this problem, but, in my case, it's was an issue related to VAGRANT.... more precisely whit Virtual Box.
I just stop the vBox proccess (i'm ussing ubuntu), remove the .lock files related to the emulator inself and that's it... the emulator should by ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I tried solutions above but nothing worked so I deleted the emulator, restart pc and create a new one and it was resolved

Answer (score 0):

Check Updates...
Emulator had an update.
After I updated and restarted.. worked fine.