# Android Studio cannot find the Visual Studio emulator

Tags: windows, android-emulator, 64-bit, visual-studio-2015

After following the [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/20/you-can-now-acquire-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-on-its-own.aspx) on using the Visual Studio Emulator for Android from Android Studio, and starting the emulator, when I am prompted to choose a running emulator, nothing shows up on the list.

I'm running Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Open an admin command prompt and enter the following; then restart the emulator.

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools" /v Path /d %localappdata%\Android\sdk
```

---

Or update the registry manually:

1. In regedit, navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node`.
2. Create a new key named `Android SDK Tools`.
3. Navigate to that key.
4. Create a new string value named `Path`. Set its value to the location of your Android SDK, which will be like `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`.

Comment: This workaround is in the blog comments, but it's buried and easy to miss.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. One additional note is you have to restart `Android Studio` after the above changes to `Registry`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with the current version of Android Studio, and VS Android Emulator on windows 8.1 (including updating with all patches to current) on a fresh install.  The emulator launches (and runs way smooth on my crappy APU - AMD 6800K, which is amusing as Googles Android Emulator runs like a bag of crap [even on my Ryzen 7 1800X] and doesn't even support AMD unless running linux, but their version of Android Studio on linux is riddled with glitches and is not clear which flavor/desktop it runs 'best' on)

Comment: Can't get it to work either with Android Studio Dolphin. I've added the registry entry with the SDK path manually, launched emulator (restarted Android Studio), but it doesn't appear in the list of (running) devices.