# "Visual Studio Android Emulator" for "Android Studio"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, emulation

I am using "Android Studio",

I want to debug my apps on "Visual Studio Android Emulator",

I did this guide :https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/20/using-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-from-android-studio-or-eclipse-with-adt/

But in "Android Studio", i can't find the emulator on "connected devices":

[image of android studio with emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKJaO.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I fixed it,
It was adb issue with my emulator because of wrong "sdk path location", 
I had to change it from Registry Editor,
Here is the solution: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx#ADB

`1-Open Registry Editor by selecting Run from the Start buttons context menu, typing regedit in the dialog box, and choosing OK.`

`2-Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools in the folder tree on the left.`

`3-Modify the Path registry variable to match the path to your Android SDK.`

Comment: Looks like `Android SDK Tools` is no longer in `Wow6432Node` registry directory. Using latest android studio & SDK on Win 10.

Comment: @Jurosh You have to create the `Android SDK Tools` key manually as explained in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31763471/431561)

Comment: Could you provide what path you are using ?  I am trying to get this to "connect" and am having the same problem where it isn't being displayed even after putting in the android sdk path into the "Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools" in the "Path" variable.