# Can't see Android Emulator when apparently it already is running

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to start learning how to develop Android apps, and I tried to make a new project and navigate through Android Studio. I tried using the Emulator by creating a new virtual device and running my new test project with it, but no matter what i seem to do it never actually does anything once I click the "Run" button on both the AVD Manager and the main one you see on the top right area of Android Studio.

[image: I keep seeing this after i try to click the Run button again after not seeing anything happen]

I keep seeing this after i try to click the Run button again after not seeing anything happen. and i can't seem to delete any of the files this is pointing to since Windows keeps complaining its being used by another application even after I close Android Studio and terminate adb.exe

I've been looking around for an answer and i've found things like "Uncheck Enable ADB Integration", or "Changing the Emulated Performance Graphics to Hardware/Software", but a lot of these answers are from threads that are 3+ years old so I don't think these are applicable anymore. can someone provide some insight to how to get this working? I am using Android Studio 3.6.3

PS: I want to make it clear that even after i restart my pc and delete these so called "*.lock" files, this changes **absolutely nothing**

Comment: Restarting the PC usually works. At least it would release the .lock file so you can delete it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a paste from my other thread on StackExchange: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/226333/cant-see-android-emulator-when-apparently-it-already-is-running

following [Robert's](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/2241/robert) advice I opted to install a copy of Genymotion Personal Edition and linked it to Android Studio via the Genymotion Plugin that was available to install.

see here for installing: https://www.techbeamers.com/genymotion-emulator/

If you do not see an additional icon pop up like described in the page then you will want to (in the case of versions around 3.6.3) enable the Toolbar via View>Appearance>Toolbar

This seems to at least link up fine for me with Android Studio, but overall does not really answer the question as to why the emulator via AVD does not function.

If no one seems to be able to share that knowledge, then I suppose will pick this one as the best answer.

Thanks to [Robert](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/2241/robert) again for mentioning Genymotion.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31031889/13826785

It could be due to the .lock files.

I hope this helps!

**Edit:**

Have you tried deleting the emulator all together and/or make a new one?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46291046/13826785

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47533260/13826785

**Edit 2:**
Try doing this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47533260/13826785
If that does not work maybe try to `Invalidate the Caches and restart` via `File`

Comment: and regarding your second edit, i am getting the same behaviour as user "a p", i click stop but nothing actually happens

Answer (score 0):

Copy the path written there and paste it in the explorer. (don't copy the *.lock part though)

Once you're there delete all the folders that have .lock at the end. After that, start the emulator again

Answer (score 0):

**Invalidate Caches / Restart**

select 'File > Invalidate Caches / Restart' and then click the 'Invalidate and Restart' button

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31969484)