# AVD shows error Error while waiting for device: Illegal char <*> at index 0: *.lock

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

Pixel 2 Api 30 AVD of my android project is not working.
It is showing me this error:
[image]

Is there anything you can do for me? Please help.

Comment: Try removing `.lock` files for your emulator, https://stackoverflow.com/a/63734419/2219237

Comment: Please, check this out https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fix-android-emulator-gets-killed-error-in-android-studio/

Comment: Now, we can use Windows PowerToys's File Locksmith to view which application locks the file in question so that we can terminate the app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/file-locksmith

Answer (score 5):

I had this error

[image]

and solved it by going to
Device Manager > Edit this AVD (pencil icon) > Show Advanced Settings > Emulated Performance > Boot Options : select "Cold Boot"

Then I restarted Android Studio and did not get the error again.

Answer (score 4):

Device Manager->options -> show on disk -> (hardware-qemu.ini.lock) delete this file, restart your ide and run your app. this worked for me

Comment: Can't delete, the file is used by another process.

Comment: it's a directory

Comment: It is a directory, but deleting the file inside (named `pid`) seems to have fixed the issue for me (I presume deleting the whole directory would also work, as it was the only file inside.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re working on API Level 30 and your emulator version is 30.1.2  then updating it to 30.1.5 would perhaps resolve your issue. Updating Emulator is a breeze, simply: Android Studio -> Go to preferences -> Android SDK -> Then find and update the Android Emulator from the list.

Answer (score 1):

I get this error sometimes, and what usually helps me is to choose "Cold boot now" on the vertical dots-menu of this virtual device.

Answer (score 0):

The option of whether to ALLOW USB debugging will pop up on it when the emulator starts up, you need to click "Allow". By the way, sometimes the popover will disappear quickly and automatically, you must be quick in sight and quick in hand. Hope that may help you.

Comment: !!!! I met the flickering window problem many times...... 
This saved me:  youtube_com/watch?v=JkBhlqjsNbI

Answer (score 0):

You can increase AVD level above 11. If you use 12 or more you will not get this error.

Comment: I'm on API 31. on fresh install of Android SDK and I get this error :(

Answer (score 0):

Just create new emulator device by: Device Manager > Create Device

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by going into device manager -> 3 dots on emulator I was using -> Wipe Data -> Cold Boot Now