# Error while waiting for device: Illegal char <*> at index 0: *.lock

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am not able to run my android application on emulator. I am getting Error while waiting for device: Illegal char <*> at index 0: *.lock. For this I deleted hardware-qemu.ini.lock folder of avd, but after deleting this when I am running app this folder is coming again and not able to launch app.

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

I tried to remove hardware-qemu.ini.lock folder of avd.

I am expecting to solve this issue.

Comment: Has this already been answered here?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73977357/avd-shows-error-error-while-waiting-for-device-illegal-char-at-index-0-l