# Android Studio : Emulator is running but not showing up on screen due to lock files

Tags: android, android-emulator, lockfile

I have lock files in my AVD and no matter if I delete the AVD or the lock files they come again when I try to run the emulator. Even if I make a new one.

[Android Studio : emulator is already running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014901/android-studio-emulator-is-already-running/31031889#comment109522535_47605997)

The above page has many solutions but none work for me. It for sure is the problem with lock files but deleting the lock files doesn't change anything as they appear back again when trying to run the emulator. I deleted them after killing the task (only the multiinstance.lock file remains after killing task) but still it appears again. I also deleted another lock file found outside the folder but still the AVD lock files appear again.(The outside one doesn't appear again so problem isn't outside the AVD).

I use android studio on windows 11. The AVD used to work before and no changes were made anywhere except shutting down my computer directly which may have resulted in lock files in avd.(my bad)

I think it may be because the posts were relatively not new. Can anyone please tell me how to delete the lock files without them appearing again. Also my emulator was working fine till yesterday. So if lock files are deleted it should work again(hopefully).